# Using mysql_num_rows(), how do I tell whether myql_query() has returned a result of 0 or an sql error in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Using php I understand that false is the same as 0, so when checking my select query results, if I have 0 results mysql_num_rows($result) will evaluate to false - this i understand, what will the function evaluate to if I have an sql error.

```
$sqlQuery="SELECT userID, userName, password, role From User WHERE userName=$userName;"
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    #I have results so process
} else #do I have an error or do I just have no results
```

I need to return a meaningful result from the query i.e. "no such user" or details of the sql error, I do not wish to use `mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die().` I have searched the web and can't find a conclusive answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Amanda

Comment: Did you surround with quotes `$userName` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can check using ===

```
if(($result = mysql_query('select * from foo')) === false) {
   // mysql error
} else {
   if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) echo 'no such user.';
}
```

or if you just want to modify your code, you could go with:

```
$sqlQuery="SELECT userID, userName, password, role From User WHERE userName=$userName;"
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    #I have results so process
} else {
    #do I have an error 
    if($result === false) {
        // mysql error indeed

    #or do I just have no results
    } else { 
        echo 'no such user';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$res=mysql_query('smth');
if(mysql_error()){//error
}
else{//correct, you can check mysql_num_rows
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure `smth` isn't valid SQL  :)

Comment: @Michael. I think OP can understand it and replace with your iwn query:)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` will return `false` on error, and the result resource otherwise.  `mysql_num_rows()` will throw a warning if you send it `false`, so you need to determine if the query worked anyway

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result === false) {
   //handle error
}
else if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
   //handle rows
}
else {
   //handle no rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
    #I have results so process
} else{ 
    echo 'No such user';
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP's typed comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to differentiate between 0 and false. So your test would become:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows > 0){
    #I have results so process
} else if ($num_rows === false) {
    #An error occured: use mysql_error for details
} else {
    #No errors, no results either
}
```